# Need simple way to compare a time string ONLY to the current dates time value

Tags: date, time, swift3, comparison

Say time string value is "7:00 AM" call it reminder time.

Now all I need to do is compare this time with the current dates time say its "9:00 AM" if reminder time is later than current time  - return true else false. This is the format "h:mm a" for date formatters.

Simple right? It should be but I have burned too much time on this. I can get hour and minute values but when the AM/PM is considered it gets harder.

I just want to compare two time values and determine if the first is later or after the second one. The date is always today or current date so I only care about the time part of the date. Of course you have to convert to dates to do the comparison but current date is easy to get however date from "7:00 AM" string does not seem to work right in comparisons.

Anyone have a function to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: First make the AM / PM as first part then add time like 'AM 7.00' or 'PM 9.00' then normally compare as string greater less comparison.  The trick is we have bigger factor of time first then smaller. So now normal comparison greater lesser will work. AM PM denotes 12 hr then next digit denotes 1 hr then next minute so now we have in proper order and you can use comparison it will work.

Comment: What we tried is to create the sortable order for time figure only..

Comment: I'm looking for a function that will take one String argument with a value like "7:00 AM"  or "7:00 PM" and compare that to the current time. If the input string time is later than the current time for current day, return true else false. Can you show me this with code?

Comment: Forgot to mention this is for Swift 3.0 and iOS in general.

Comment: yeah not its good, at least you told about the lang platform your are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the approach would be lets date the `Date()` object from your current time object so you will get

> default date + your time = `2000-01-01 00:00:00` +`your time (7.00 AM or 9.00 PM)`

now we will get the current time from today only, in same format. (Only time)

> it will be something like `3.56 PM`

now again we will convert this `3.56 PM` to `Date()` with default date as prev. so now we will have two date time object with same Date(2000-01-01) and respective times.

- 2000-01-01 7:00:00   => this will your 7.00 AM with default date
- 2000-01-01 15:56:00   => this will be current time with default date

now we will compare two date object.

**Check the fiddle [Fiddle](https://iswift.org/playground?oT0UzJ)**

```
func CompareMyTimeInString(myTime:String)->Bool
{
    // create the formatter - we are expecting only "hh:mm a" format
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_GB")

    // default date with my time
    var dt_MyTime = dateFormatter.date(from: yourTime)!

    // current time in same format as string "hh:mm a"
    var currentTimString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date());
    print("Current Time is - "+currentTimString);

    // current time with default date.
    var dt_CurrentTime = dateFormatter.date(from: currentTimString)!

    // now just compare two date objects :)
    return dt_MyTime > dt_CurrentTime;
}



// then call it like 
var yourTime = "7.00 AM"
var isDue = CompareMyTimeInString(myTime:yourTime);
print(isDue);
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work using a different approach which included having the date format being the "none" option. But your method works from what I see as well. I'll attach my solution as well and give you credit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was as follows.

private func ReminderAfterCurrentTime(reminderTimeString: String) -> Bool {
    //Compare the two time strings and if reminderTimeString is later than current time string
    //return true since Reminder is after current time.

```
//Get the current date and time
let currentDateTime = Date()

// Create calendar object
let calendar = NSCalendar.current

// Get current date hour and minute values for comparison.
let currentHourValue = Int(calendar.component(.hour, from: currentDateTime))
let currentMinuteValue = Int(calendar.component(.minute, from: currentDateTime))

//Now get a date from the time string passed in so we can get just the hours and minutes to compare
let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
dateformatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none
dateformatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short

//Now get the date using formatter.
let reminderDateTime = dateformatter.date(from: reminderTimeString)
print("reminderDateTime = \(reminderDateTime)")

//Get reminder hour and minute for comparison.
let reminderHourValue = Int(calendar.component(.hour, from: reminderDateTime!))
let reminderMinuteValue = Int(calendar.component(.minute, from: reminderDateTime!))

print("currentHourValue = \(currentHourValue)")
print("currentMinuteValue = \(currentMinuteValue)")
print("reminderHourValue = \(reminderHourValue)")
print("reminderMinuteValue = \(reminderMinuteValue)")


//This works due to 24 hour clock. Thus AM/PM is already taken into account.
if currentHourValue < reminderHourValue {
    return true
}

//Check for same hour then use minutes
if currentHourValue == reminderHourValue {
    if currentMinuteValue < reminderMinuteValue {
        return true
    }
}

//Otherwise return false
return false
```

}